# Deprecation Warning with Node.js - (Global is deprecated) but 'Global' is not mentioned

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to use map on an array i got from query sent to my DB (WebApp for managing vacation packages) 
I got an Error message: (node:67666) [DEP0016] DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
But i did't use Global at all...
Please help...

```
router.get('/vacs_graph', async (req, res, next) => {
  let q = `SELECT * FROM vacations`;
  let resp = await pool.query(q);
  var allprom=[];
  var result = [];

resp.forEach(v => {
  let q2 = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM VacVsUser WHERE vacationID=${v.id}` 
  allprom.push(pool.query(q2))
});
Promise.all(allprom).then(data=>
  {
    result = resp.map((v,i) => {
      v["followed"] = data[i][0]["counter"]


    })
  })
  res.json(result)
})
```

expected to get array full of objects with another key inside the objects ("followed") that represent the number of time a vacation package was selected to be followed.

Comment: can you please mention what other libraries are you using/requiring in your code? Or try to make sure that you are using latest packages nothing is old or obsolete version.

Comment: promise-mysql v3.3.2
express-session v1.16.2
socket.io v2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with the aws-sdk when I was running an express nodejs server on port 80. I changed the server port to 3050 and it resolved the issue.

I also upgraded my version of node to the latest lts version. To check your node version open a command prompt and run

```
node --version
```

If this error is coming from your own code, change the capitalisation of "GLOBAL" to "global"